# The Cartan is a complex vector space but the root system is real?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems

Let $\frak{g}$ be a complex semisimple Lie algebra with some choice of Cartan subalgebra $\frak{h}$. The dual space $\frak{h}^* = \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(\frak{h},\mathbb{C})$ is a complex vector space, and the associated root system lives in $\frak{h}^*$, taken with the dual of the Killing form.

Now for an abstract root system one considers a real Euclidean vector space $E$ together with a special subset $R \subseteq E$. Why does one not consider a complex space, since $\frak{h}^*$ is complex. I guess it is because the roots are integer combinations of any choice of simple roots and hence they identify a special real subspace of $\frak{h}^*$, and also that on this space the dual Killing is real inner product. Is my reasoning corrrect?

Comment: Yes, I think that your reasoning is correct,

Comment: I prefer to consider a semisimple complex algebraic group $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$. Let $T\subset G$ be a maximal torus. Then the root system $R(G,T)$ is contained in the lattice $X^*(T)$ of the characters of $T$, which is a finitely generated free $\mathbb Z$-module (finitely generated free abelian group). Thus all is defined over $\Bbb Z$, hence over $\Bbb Q$, hence over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: One thing to note as well is that when you take a real form of $\mathfrak{g}$, the corresponding real subspace of $\mathfrak{h}^*$ does not have to coincide with the one the roots live in (unless it is a split real form) and the different possibilities there are effectively encoded in the Satake diagram.

Comment: Related questions answered on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3312731/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2746923/96384.